# Angular2 error: No provider for RadioControlRegistry

Tags: angularjs, angular

i am using angular 2 RC5  `"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5"` `"@angular/forms": "0.3.0"`

i am using radio button as below

```
<input type="radio" name="option" [value]="true" [(ngModel)]="option.checked">
```

but when i am run i am getting the following error
`No provider for RadioControlRegistry`. what is the problem here?

below is my app.module

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        routing,
        HttpModule,
        JsonpModule 
    ]
....
```

Comment: Have you included as a module?

Comment: @ClydeLobo  i included my app.module now. is this you are asking or something else?

Comment: What it says if you try to add this, `<input type="radio" name="option" [value]="true" >`? check first without `[ngModel]`

Comment: I think you should update to final instead of debugging RC.5

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i am mid of my project so i dont want to update now

Comment: @micronyks yes without ngModel its working. but i want to bind the check status to checked property

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  ok do you think that is the problem, if it so i can try that

Comment: Yes. so probably problem is with [ngModel] and so with model `option.checked`. how do you handle `option.checked` ?

Comment: @micronyks i did update my angular version to final. now it showing error as i need to declare all my directives in ngModule. i am doing that now

Comment: @micronyks ok after declared all components to ngmodule application start working also radio button.if you add the suggestion as answer i am happy to accept